# Did select Method did not work properly some time it stuck

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using new method of collection view but it does not work proper I am using this code in did select method. is it right way to perform an action in did select?
I'm getting a second long delay when selecting my collectionview cell. Here is my current code for collection view did select:

```
      if let selectedItemIdentifier = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) {
        if  selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "Manual", image: manualImage)){
           // code
        }
        if  selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "Auto", image: autoImages)){
           
             // code
        }
        if  selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "Restore", image: restoreImage)){
             // code
        }
        if  selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "Lasso", image: lassoImages)){
           
            
          // code
        }
        if  selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "Smooth", image: featherImages)){
            // code
        }
        if  selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "openGallary")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            showPhotoLibrary()
            autoBtnUI()
            removeCircle()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "Color")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            openColorPicker()
            autoBtnUI()
            removeCircle()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini1")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge1")
            
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini2")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge2")
           
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini3")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge3")
           
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini4")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge4")
            
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini5")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge5")
           
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini6")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge6")
            
            
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini7")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge7")
           
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini8")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge8")
            
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini9")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge9")
           
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "BackgroundMini10")!)){
            buttonTap = "Background"
            middleImageView.isHidden = false
            lassoimageView.isHidden = true
            middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundLarge10")
            
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "overlayMini1")!)){
            buttonTap = "Overlay"
            overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "OverlayLarge1")
            
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "overlayMini2")!)){
            buttonTap = "Overlay"
            overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "OverlayLarge2")
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }

        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "overlayMini5")!)){
            buttonTap = "Overlay"
            overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "OverlayLarge5")
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "overlayMini6")!)){
            buttonTap = "Overlay"
            overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "OverlayLarge6")
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "overlayMini7")!)){
            buttonTap = "Overlay"
            overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "OverlayLarge7")
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }
        if selectedItemIdentifier == .symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "overlayMini8")!)){
            buttonTap = "Overlay"
            overlayImage.image = UIImage(named: "OverlayLarge8")
            removeCircle()
            autoBtnUI()
        }

        
    }
```

There seems to be an issue with my CollectionView Did select function. If switch my code in my didSelect function for a print statement, there is no longera delay.

Comment: For a start you can consider using `else if` or `switch`.

Comment: You need that complex thing `.symbol(SFSymbolItem(name: "", image: UIImage(named: "Color")!)` for identifier? Could that be simplified? The `else` would avoid doing all the remaining tests if you succeed in the first one.

Comment: I don't know if it can be simplified or not but else if condition does not work @Larme

Comment: Try to monitor what really takes time. We can't guess. Could be any of the code inside an `if`... If you comment all the codes inside the `if`, is it quicker?